# How many graphs are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

If there are 5 vertices and between every pair of vertices at most 3 edges are allowed. How many such graphs are possible ?

---

Is the count $4^{10}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each pair you have $4$ possibilities and the number of all pairs is ${5\choose 2}=10$, so the answer should be $4^{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are $10$ pairs of vertices in a graph with $5$ vertices, and if each of them can have almost $3$ edges (that means, possibilities are $0$, $1$, $2$ and $3$ edges $\equiv 4$ possibilities), so what does that imply?